# Removing every instance of a duplicate from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there way to remove every instance of duplicates in Pandas?  I don't see an option in [`drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). Is there any way perhaps of getting the indices of the duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [12]: df[~(df.duplicated() | df.duplicated(take_last=True))]
Out[12]:
   0  1
3  3  4
```

Perhaps there's a better way!

Comment: Thanks! What if we want to do this based on the duplicates of a specific set of columns (but still get the result on the full dataframe)?

Comment: @user815423426 you can use the subset argument for duplicated, ie `df[~(df.duplicated(subset=cols) | df.duplicated(subset=cols, take_last=True))]`.